# ¿Encode64 en Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, oracle

Como hago para realizar un encode64 a una consulta

Esta es mi consulta

```
select id_solicitud from sol_solicitud where id_solicitud=506
```

Mi consulta me trae 506, Pero necesito que la consulta me retorne con encode64 es decir que aparezca así

```
NTA2
```

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba la siguiente función:

*Sintaxis*:

```
UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE (
   r  IN RAW) 
RETURN RAW;
```

Parámetro `r`: El valor RAW a codificar.

`RAW`: Contiene la base codificada de 64.

*Tu caso:*

```
UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE (
    select id_solicitud from sol_solicitud where id_solicitud=506 IN RAW) 
    RETURN RAW;
```

Más info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_encode.htm#i999460

Comment: Gracias Funciona correctamente, saludos.